# MySql Error "Unknown column 'inDate' in 'where clause'"

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to run this stored procedure in MySql. But its throwing an Error:

```
"Unknown column 'inDate' in 'where clause"


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Cus_Emails`(inDate varchar(10))

truncate table tt;
insert  tt(CompanyName, CustomerNumber, ServicePoint, EmailAddressSequenc, EmailAddress, 
CustomerBusinessUnit)
select distinct '01' CompanyName, s.CustomerNo CustomerNumber, if(d.LINE_DESC like '%/%', substring_index(d.LINE_DESC, '/', -1), '') ServicePoint, '01' EmailAddressSequenc, 'Invoice.inbox@healthscope.com.au' EmailAddress, s.ServicePoint CustomerBusinessUnit
from doc_details d join doc_refs r on d.REF_ID=r.REF_ID
Join service_points s On s.CustomerNo=Trim(substring_index(substring_index(d.LINE_DESC, '/', 1), ' ', -1))
where d.ENTRY_ID like concat(inDate, '%') and d.PAGE_NUM=1 And d.LINE_NUM in (1,2) And (d.LINE_DESC like '-%' Or d.LINE_DESC Like '0%') and d.doc_type='INV'
Union 
select distinct '01' CompanyName, s.CustomerNo CustomerNumber, if(d.LINE_DESC like '%/%', substring_index(d.LINE_DESC, '/', -1), '') ServicePoint, '01' EmailAddressSequenc, 'Invoice.inbox@healthscope.com.au' EmailAddress, s.ServicePoint CustomerBusinessUnit
from doc_details d join doc_refs r on d.REF_ID=r.REF_ID
Join service_points s On s.CustomerNo=Trim(substring_index(substring_index(d.LINE_DESC, '/', 1), ' ', -1))
where d.ENTRY_ID like concat(inDate, '%') and d.PAGE_NUM=1 And d.LINE_NUM in (3)  and d.doc_type='CRE';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-procedure.html):

I'd guess that ....

> routine_body:
>       Valid SQL procedure statement

means you have to enclose your statements (`truncate`, `insert`) in `BEGIN` `END`. Otherwise *routine_body* is only the `truncate` and the variable `inDate` is out of procedure scope.

Answer (score -7):

Because, in your table, you don't have `inDate` column.

Check the column name again and correct it!

Comment: what is cos,ur,u here?, use appropriate words and one Important point: **do read the question before answering**

Comment: because in your table, inDate column does not exists. that's why mySQL is giving you "Unknown column 'inDate' in 'where clause in your "where condition"

Comment: plz dun spk txtspk. This is SO; Textspeak is unreadable, and you are not limited in the amount of characters you can put in your answer.

Comment: Text speak aside, you clearly didn't read the question. `inDate` is a procedure parameter, not a column from a table.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. parameter act as a temp column name am i right to say that?mysql already clearly stated the error out. it has to do with column name or spelling or declaration if you have not